# A rebus for the morning

Tags: word, rebus

Need to complete the answer to this rebus soon or I'll be late for work!

[image]

Hint:

> The answer is a 9-letter word

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> **BREAKFAST**. The guy is doing an emergency stop, and is having to 'brake fast'.